# Probability distribution with constant Laplace transfom

Tags: probability, laplace-transform

What is the probability distribution with Laplace transform equals $a$, $a \in (0,1)$?

I think it is the distribution with mass $a$ at zero and mass $1-a$ at infinity?

The same question in the bivariate case.

Comment: Sounds like a Dirac delta, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you mean with mass $1-a$ at infinity ? The only probability measure $\mathbb{P}[X \in A]$ giving $\mathbb{E}[e^{- s X}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-sx} d\mathbb{P}[X \le x] = 1$ is $\mathbb{P}[X \le x] = 1_{x \ge 0}$ the [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) whose pdf is the Dirac delta. If $X$ is a $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued random variable then the answer is the same, assuming you defined its Laplace transform as $\mathbb{E}[e^{- \langle s, X \rangle}]$ an analytic function in $s=  (s_1,\ldots,s_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ @SeanRoberson

Comment: I mean degenerate distribution.